# Prove that for $a_k>0,$ if $\sum a_k^2$ converges, then $\sum \frac{a_k}k$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove that for for $a_k>0,$ if $\sum a_k^2$ converges, then $\sum \frac{a_k}k$ converges.
I was given this in an introductory calculus class, where I was only taught the basic convergence tests. I’ve tried limit comparison, power series, direct comparison, all to no avail. I have tried proving the contrapositive, using integrals as well, but the limit comparison with any series I’ve tried just goes to 0 or infinity which is inconclusive. My searches on MSE just yield the simpler problem of “if$\sum a_k$ converges then prove $\sum a_k^2$ converges“, and searches on google turned up nothing. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I suppose you are not allowed to use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality ?

Comment: No need here for the full Cauchy-Schwarz, just note that $\frac{a_k}{k} \leq a_k^2+k^{-2}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2\ge0$ hence, $ab\le \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$. Hence, for any $n$ you have that $0\le \frac{a_n}{n}\le\frac{a_n^2+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2}$, so
$$0\le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}\le\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$
So, if $\sum a_n^2$ converges, so it does $\sum\frac{a_n}{n}$.

Comment: Since $\sum n^{-2}=\pi^2/6$ converges.